# Run 100 different set of commands in Shell

Tags: shell, sh

I would like to run a copy command from one server to aws bucket every 20 minutes hour . I can put this in for loop but I have a confusion since I have 1000 different file names(keep on adding on daily basis) .It is really tough to do it manually  . Need to automate the stuff . I have all the 1000 commands ready with me in a notepad.Below commands should run as a batch exmaple filename1,1a should execute at 10.AM and after 20 minutes filename2,2a should go.

Needed output :

Aws s3 cp filename1.txt /path1 
aws s3 cp filename1a.txt /path1

Aws s3 cp filename2.txt /path2
aws s3 cp filename2a.txt /path2

In the above example , I would like to copy filename1,1a should be copied to path1 10:00AM and after 20 minutes Filename2 should copy to path2 . I have all the commands ready . Just need to execute after 20 minutes on sequence and the same file should not repeat again .

SORRY FOR THE BASIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a timeout, or use windows task scheduler to just schedule them 20 mins apart.

```
Aws s3 cp filename1.txt /path1 aws s3 cp filename1a.txt /path1
timeout 1200
Aws s3 cp filename2.txt /path2 aws s3 cp filename2a.txt /path2
```

Comment: Need to do in Linux shell script .